# Azure RM VM hard disks

Tags: azure, azure-storage, vhd, iaas

I have created an Azure RM VM with premium unmanaged disk configuration. I have 1 OS disk 127gb and a temp disk with size 56gb. My OS disk also contains SQL Server and SharePoint 2013. When I navigate to the storage account that contains my unmanaged OS disk I see 2 vhd images.

[image]

I have downloaded both. The one ending with 110 seems to be a clean Windows 2012 R2 OS disk. The vhd ending with 448 sees to be the image containing Windows, SQL and SharePoint.

Why do I see two vhd's? Can I delete the one ending with 110?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the one that doesnt show leased is not being used by a vm (at least not any RUNNING vm). so if you have only 1 vm - it should be safe to delete it (because its not attached to it).

Comment: I deleted the disk and everything still works. Maybe it was a left over of some other machine I created in the past.